# Managing SVN repo config files

Tags: svn, version-control, configuration-management

We've had some problems with the .conf files for subversion.  I'd really like the configuration files for all subversion repos to be version controled so if someone fat fingers something in a conf file the repo doesn't go down.  We don't want the conf folder to be an actual svn checkout location.

Has anyone found a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Thanks, like all these answers.  Still working with my team to decide which approach to use.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate repository for the svn configurations where you only have admin access.
Optionally you can create a deployment script in that repository that copies all config files to relevant directories.

Answer (score 1):

`git` will be ideal for versioning the config files. Just `git init` and add the files there.

Creating an SVN repo and then checking out a working copy and adding files would work as well, but is not as lightweight as git in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The Subversion universe might help here with [fsvs](http://fsvs.tigris.org/purpose.html). Basically: A Subversion client which does not work with working copies but with plain directories. The associated metadata is stored outside the managed directories.

So you could use Subversion itself for management without having the `.svn` metadata inside the configuration data.